# ERROR TypeError: _co.collapsed is not a function?

Tags: angular

My HTML template which makes use of `ngFor` as follows,

```
<div class="card" *ngFor="let item of mydataarray">
<div class="card-header" (click)="item.isCollapsed = !item.isCollapsed">
<div class="card-body" [collapse]="item.isCollapsed">
.. Body of my card
</div>
</div>                
</div>
```

In the above code when I try loading this page with `mydataarray` with a valid value.

I get the valid value in `item` e.g. `{{ item.isCollapsed }}` returns `true` but when I try using it as `[collapse]="item.isCollapsed"` it throws error as follows:

```
ERROR TypeError: _co.collapsed is not a function
```

I think the problem is with the `item.isCollapsed` field passed, If I declare the field without object e.g. `isCollapsed` & use it in my template as `[collapse]="isCollapsed"` it works, I am not sure how do I pass subfield here.

So how can I bind the subfield `isCollapsed` of `item` with `[collapse]`?

***Update***

Based on the answer by [Krishna Rathore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7584231/krishna-rathore) I tried `*ngIf="item.isCollapsed"`that also didn't work.

So I investigated further found that the value returning function in my component file was as below:

```
get mydataarray() {
    if(this.mydataarray) {
       // Some pre-processing on data which was not erroneous
       return this.mydataarray;
    } else {
       return null;
    }   
}
```

So I simply removed the processing part to a different place where I get the value for `mydataarray` first time & changed the function to return the static value which is pre-processed, as follows

```
get mydataarray() {
           return this.mydataarray;
    }
```

Now collapse is happening even with `[collapse]="item.isCollapsed"` & also with `*ngIf="item.isCollapsed"`.

Though I am not able to fully understand what's wrong with doing pre-processing 
 part in the `get mydataarray()` method.

Comment: do you want to expand/collapse card-body ?

Comment: @KrishnaRathore yes but based on the value in `item.isCollapsed`, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try this solution.

I have created [stackbliz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/cocollapsed-is-not-a-function)

```
<div class="card" *ngFor="let item of mydataarray">
  <div class="card-header" (click)="item.isCollapsed = !item.isCollapsed">
    Header
  </div>
  <div class="card-body" *ngIf="item.isCollapsed">
    <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
    <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 for the efforts answering my question, but something weird happened, Hence not accepted as an answer, Can you take a look at the updated part of the question? Thanks